# Setup distinct keys for React Elements within an HOC which renders different components based on props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aware as to why the keys are required for React Elements and that they need to be unique. Most of the times we can resolve this by providing some unique key from the data as React key.

Currently the problem statement is that I have a single HOC component, a Carousel that renders multiple cards within it. Which component card it needs to rendered is driven by a cardType prop, As it can contain customerCards, reviewCards and various other types of cards within it.The data for each of the cards may have a different key as a unique identifier.

In this case i tried making use of the index property for generating unique keys, but on further inspection came across various examples where this leads to unexpected behaviours. So I tried a different solution.

My solution : I have written a mapper which maps the type to the key name and while rendering key is assigned on the basis of type prop.

for eg:- `carouselConfig = { customer: 'name', reviewCard: 'reviewNo', queryCard: 'queryId' }`

Within the carouselComponent we can assign the key as, `key = cardData[carouselConfig[cardType]]` where the cardType prop defines the card to be rendered and it will drive as to from where the key is set for the rendered component.

Is this the correct way to do it ? Or is there any alternate approach that can be applied in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost... if the values within a field are unique, but might be duplicated between different fields, e.g. `queryId=1` and `reviewNo=1` on 2 different cards, you can ensure unique key like this:

```
key = `${cardType}-$cardData[carouselConfig[cardType]]}`
```

...assuming extensive tests to make sure there is no typo in the config, that the fields actually exist in real data and values are unique.

Comment: Actually the queryId is some randomly generated string so this duplication will not happen. Although i like the idea of appending the cardType to the key.